# PyQt5 - Issue opening windows depending on results of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I've been working with PyQt5 and as part of my program, the first window is login_gui.py. It is simply two input fields (employee number & employee pin) and a log in button. All users are stored in a SQLite db, including an admin user (who has 'admin' for employee number and pin) and some more sample users.

In my application, I also have two more windows: gui.py and viewpayroll_employee_gui.py. The program initializes through a file called brains.py, which launches login_gui.py.

Anyways, I'm attempting to make it so that if a user enters 'admin' for number and pin, they'll be shown the gui.py window ONLY and if they enter a user in the database, they'll be shown the viewpayroll_employee_gui.py window. The code below (brains.py) opens both files, as I can't seem to use an if condition inside "def main():" that'll direct users to each window accorindingly.

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now. Any help would be seriously appreciated.

```
from login_gui import Ui_MainWindow as log_in_window
    from gui import Ui_MainWindow as home_page_window
    from viewpayroll_employee_gui import Ui_EmployeePayrollWindow as payroll_window
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    
    
    class Main_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, home_page_window):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Main_Window, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
    
    class Payroll_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, payroll_window):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Payroll_Window, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
    
        def openWindow(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.ui = payroll_window()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
    
    class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, log_in_window):
        logged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.btn_logIn.clicked.connect(self.authenticate)
    
        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
        def authenticate(self):
            db_user = self.employeeNumInput.text()
            db_pass = self.employeePinInput.text()
    
            result = LoginWindow.login(self, emp_number=db_user, pin_number=db_pass)
            print(f"TESTING RESULT: {result}")
            if result[0][0] == 'admin' and result[0][1] == 'admin':
                print("Logged in as ADMIN.")
                windowlogin = LoginWindow()
                w = Main_Window()
                w.show()
                self.logged.emit()
                self.close()
            elif result == "None":
                print("No results found!")
    
            else:
                print("Logged in as EMPLOYEE.")
            return result
    
    def main():
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        windowlogin = LoginWindow()
        w = Main_Window()
        pwind = Payroll_Window()
        windowlogin.show()
        windowlogin.logged.connect(w.show)
        windowlogin.logged.connect(pwind.show)
    
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Here is some of the code inside login_gui.py, I've cut out a good chunk of the code as it's pretty much exclusively just UI related code but kept the function that handles getting data from the db:

```
def login(self, emp_number, pin_number):
    try:
        #emp_number = self.employeeNumInput.text()
        #pin_number = self.employeePinInput.text()
        result = check_user_log_in(emp_number, pin_number)

        if result == "None":
            print("Error signing in!!!")
            return "No results found!"
        elif result[0][0] == "admin" and result[0][1] == "admin":
            print("Success!")
            return result
        else:
            return result

    except:
        print("Error signing in.")
```

Comment: In the `authenticate` method, you're emitting the `self.logged` signal after connecting it to `w.show` and `pwind.show` in `main`. This causes both windows to appear no matter what additional logic you may have in `authenticate`.

Comment: Originally, there was only login related auth in that method, and nothing to do with showing windows. I think the problem I'm having is setting some conditional around the two: windowlogin.logged.connect(w.show)
    windowlogin.logged.connect(pwind.show) near the end of the code. One should only be triggered at any given time.

Comment: @MantleLoL I believe you're a bit confused on how signals/slots work and how/when functions are executed and their instructions evaluated. The connection to `logged` is created on startup, whatever you do in `authenticate` won't matter, since it will be called *after* the button is clicked. You have to create a signal that also emits an argument and connect to a function will decide what window to open depending on that argument. You are also creating two `Main_Window` instances.